# Display div for few seconds and disappear using asp.net code behind

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!Page.IsPostBack)
                divStatus.Visible = true;
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "somekey", "function autoHide(){ setTimeout(function() {document.getlementById('" + divStatus.ClientID + "').style.display='none';},5000);};", true); 
        }

  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div class="success" id="divStatus" runat="server" visible="false" >sssssssssssssssss</div>

    </div>
    </form>
```

what exactly do i need to add in order to fadeout by itself after few seconds? currently i am displaying div but the user have to click explcitly to close the div and is there a way to close the div by itself using asp.net?

yes i know it does work with fadein and fadeout if you provide the timer but it does not work with asp.net code behind.

//html:

```
 <div class="success" id="divStatus" runat="server" visible="false" ></div>
```

//code behind:

```
protected void lnkbtn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ........//more code for deleting
       if (deleted)
       {
           divStatus.visible = true;
       }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes i know it does work with fadein and fadeout if you provide the
>   timer but it does not work with asp.net code behind.

There's no difference. ASP.NET controls render as regular html controls. My hunch is that you are not using the proper client ID that's rendered. You have two choices:

- Add ClientIDMode="static" in your markup as so:

  ```
  <div clientidmode="static" class="success" id="divStatus" runat="server" visible="false" ></div>
  ```

And then add the javascript function to automatically hide the div:

```
function autoHide()
{  //hide after 5 seconds
   setTimeout(function(){document.getlementById('divStatus').style.display='none';},5000);
}
```

- simply use `<%=divStatus.ClientID%>` to get the client id that's
  ultimately rendered on the page as so:

  ```
  function autoHide() {  //hide after 5 seconds   
    setTimeout(function() {document.getlementById('<%=divStatus.ClientID%>').style.display='none';},5000);
  }
  ```

From codebehind, you can simply call:

```
 ........//more code for deleting
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"somekey","autoHide();",false);
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to even define the `autoHide` function in code behind, do as follows (note that the last parameter is `true` in this case, as opposed to `false` on the previous example):

```
 ........//more code for deleting
string script = @"document.getElementById('" + divStatus.ClientID + "').innerHTML='You are done!' ;setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('" + divStatus.ClientID + "').style.display='none';},5000);";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "somekey", script, true);
```

Comment: is there a way i can have the `autoHide()` in code behind so i don't depend on the .aspx code if i am using the code behind? and the second thing is that i am using div with runat="server" and i am showing the div based on the condition of my logic to visible = true so if i just visible = true will that be enough ?

Comment: I don't follow very well your first question. In regards to your second question, the answer is yes.

Comment: You could run Icarus suggested function autoHide() on document.ready event with Jquery:
$(document).ready(function() {
   autoHide();
 });
This obviously having declared the function somewhere in your page previously.

Comment: what i was trying to say that, is that possible to put autoHide function in code behind?

Comment: thanks lcarus, 1+ .. i have asked new question related with that i have asked here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593041/displaying-div-passing-text-from-code-behind

Comment: updated my code... does not work... i run the page and i see the div but it never goes after 5 seconds and i waited for long and still there...

Comment: @issoa Check the Update section again, I changed it. You only need to specify the contents of the script, without giving it the function name as I was doing initially.