# displaying div passing text from code-behind

Tags: asp.net

how to pass the text message along with this function to display on the div? from code behind

```
 <div class="success" id="divStatus" runat="server" visible="false" ></div>


Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"somekey","function autoHide(){ setTimeout(function() {document.getlementById('"+divStatus.ClientID+"').style.display='none';},5000);};",true);
```

Comment: What JS framework are you using?

Comment: where are you calling the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 string script = @"document.getElementById('" + divStatus.ClientID + "').innerHTML='You are done!' ;setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('" + divStatus.ClientID + "').style.display='none';},5000);";
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "somekey", script, true);
```

The effect will be: Change the inner HTML of the divStatus div to say "You are done" and then it will disappear the div after 5 seconds.

Comment: does not really work when i have the above code in my update-panel but if i just have a plain .aspx code it does work... any idea?