# hide a div and lable after 5 second using javascript/jquery function in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Here is the div:

```
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" runat="server" visible="false" id="lblmsgid">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
             <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblmsg" Font-Bold="true" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                  </div>
```

I want to hide the div after few second using client side code.
Here i am using c# in backend.

```
  else if (e.CommandName.Equals("CategoryDelete"))
            {
                objCategory.CategoryDelete(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
                lblmsgid.Visible = true;
                lblmsg.Text = "Delete Successful..";
                BindCategory();
            }
```

After click on delete button from my grid i want to show a error message in the above lable(lable is in the div) and after few second i want to hide the div..
how can i do??

here is the button for activate:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnActivate" runat="server" OnClick="BtnActivate_Click" CssClass="btn-active" Text="Activate Selected" OnClientClick="javascript:return TestCheckBox();" />
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: show your click-event handle for the button.

Comment: yes i have already edited you look the code..i am following..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591013/display-div-for-few-seconds-and-disappear-using-asp-net-code-behind

Comment: @ManojMaharana, show your `TestCheckBox()` function

Comment: look the above code..ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `setTimeout`. With plain js:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    var alerts = document.getElementsByClassName("alert-dismissable");
  
    for( var i = 0; i < alerts.length; i++ ) {
        alerts[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" runat="server" visible="false" id="lblmsgid">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
  <label runat="server" ID="lblmsg" Font-Bold="true" Visible="false">asd</label>
</div>
```

Or with jQuery:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert-dismissable").hide();
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" runat="server" visible="false" id="lblmsgid">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
  <label runat="server" ID="lblmsg" Font-Bold="true" Visible="false">asd</label>
</div>
```

Comment: here how you call setTimeOut fUNCTION FROM DIV??

Comment: I don't understand your questsion?! @ManojMaharana

Comment: i want to show lable message  dynamically..why you are using <label runat="server" ID="lblmsg" Font-Bold="true" Visible="false">asd</label>??i have edited above you just look.

Comment: I used this for working examples here on SO. You should set the timeout whenever you dynamically added the alert. Just as shown in my example. I don't understand what question you else got?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591013/display-div-for-few-seconds-and-disappear-using-asp-net-code-behind

Comment: the same thing i want to do in the above stack overflow link...without using  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "somekey", "autoHide();", false);

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.alert-dismissable').hide();
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#lblmsgid').hide();
    }, 5 * 1000); //hides after 5 seconds
});
```

Comment: really? -1? who was that? are you gonna tell that this will not work?

Comment: It's likely because you haven't explained your answer

Comment: is there any solution??

Comment: @arjabbar, thanx =)

Comment: @ManojMaharana, I asked you a question, in the comments to your question...

Comment: @ManojMaharana, show your click-event handle for the button.